# access elements within an object of array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object $invoiceitems - its a (smarty) object of array of arrays.
I cannot work out how to access values within it.

For example how would I access 'relid' element in the second array?

```
//print_r($invoiceitems);
```

> Smarty_Variable Object ( [value] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] =>
>   40442 [type] => Hosting [relid] => 2913 [description] => TESTING
>   [rawamount] => 24.00 [amount] => €24.00 EUR [taxed] => 1 ) [1] =>
>   Array ( [id] => 40443 [type] => Hosting [relid] => 2913 [description]
>   => TESTING [rawamount] => 24.00 [amount] => €24.00 EUR [taxed] => 1 ) ) [nocache] => [scope] => 0 )

Answer (score 1):

you can do by this:

```
foreach($invoiceitems  as $row){
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['type'];
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the arrays are held within the `value` property of the object. So, to get the outer array, you'd use:

`$invoiceitems->value`

Then, to get `relid` from the second array:

`$invoiceitems->value[1]['relid']`